# why do we write [0] in the code which i specified?

Tags: javascript, html, css

why do we write `(item.classList[0] === "complete-btn")`

like what is `"item.classList[0]"` and why is it 0 [0] here ?

```
if(item.classList[0] === "complete-btn"){
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle("completed"); 
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classList` is a [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) of the class names on an element. You can index into the list the way you do with arrays to access the individual tokens (classes, in this case) in the list. For instance, if you have `class="a b c"`, then `.classList[0]` is `"a"`, `.classList[1]` is `"b"`, and `.classList[2]` is `"c"`. **But**, keep reading.

The author of the code in the question decided it made sense to see if the **first** class in the list was `complete-btn`. This is poor practice, because the order of classes in the class list is not important and it can change as classes are added and removed from the list.¹ For that reason, it would be better written with [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains):

```
if (item.classList.contains("complete-btn")) {
```

The original code would fail for an element with `class="example complete-btn"`, whereas the code using `contains` doesn't:

```js
const item = document.querySelector(".example");
console.log(item.classList[0] === "complete-btn");    // false, [0] is "example"
console.log(item.classList.contains("complete-btn")); // true
```

```html
<div class="example complete-btn"></div>
```

---

¹ *"This is poor practice, because the order of classes in the class list is not important and it can change as classes are added and removed from the list."* Granted, if `complete-btn` is the first class listed in the `class` attribute of the HTML and that class is never removed via `.classList.remove` or `.classList.toggle`, it will remain the first in the list; still, it's poor practice to rely on it, not least because someone maintaining the HTML could add another class at the beginning, not realizing the JavaScript was relying on order — because in general, there is no order to the classes in `class`.

Comment: @Teemu - Yeah, I've beefed up the "why" there. I mean, it's true that if it's `class="complete-btn x y"` in the HTML and you never remove `complete-btn` from the list, it will always be the first in the list (`DOMTokenList`'s spec guarantees that), but still, someone doing maintenance could update the HTML not realizing the JavaScript relied on it being the first... :-)

Answer (score 0):

`item.classlist` returns a DOMTokenList Object which is like an array and has all classes in it. Here we are accessing its first class from the array that's why 0.